# How to read self closing tag's attribute in xml?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

I have this type of xml:

```
<trace>
    <string key="id" value="1"/>
    <event>
        <string key="Hello" value="1"/>
        <string key="World" value="2"/>
    </event>
    <event>
        <string key="Stack" value="3"/>
        <string key="Overflow" value="4"/>
    </event>
</trace>
```

I want to read the key attributes here.

I already wrote this code:

```
    try {

        File fXmlFile = new File("C:\\sampleXml.xes");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile.toString());

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nListTrace = doc.getElementsByTagName("trace");

        for (int j = 0; j < nListTrace.getLength(); j++) {

            Node nNode = nListTrace.item(j);

            NodeList nListEvent = doc.getElementsByTagName("event");

            for(int i = 0 ; i < nListEvent.getLength(); i++){

                Node nNodeEvent = nListEvent.item(i);

                Element eElement = (Element) nNodeEvent;

                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNodeEvent.getNodeName());

            }
        }

    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How can i get all elements in events? How can i get access to attributes in element which has self closing tag?

Comment: Maybe you should consider a sax-parser? Look at this link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to iterate the *structure* of the XML, don't use `doc.getElementsByTagName()` in a nested loop. That method basically ignore the XML structure and locates all elements of the given name, *regardless* of where the element is located.

So, first, why use `getElementsByTagName("trace")` if `<trace>` is the root element. Just call `doc.getDocumentElement()` to get the root element.

Also, whether a tag is given as `<string key="id"/>` or `<string key="id"></string>`, the result DOM tree will be exactly the same, so there is no special consideration for handling self-closing tags, when using DOM.

If you want to iterate the content of an `<event>` element, you can:

1. Iterate child nodes using `elem.getFirstChild()` and `elem.getNextSibling()`.
2. Iterate child nodes using `elem.getChildNodes()`.
3. Iterate descendant elements using `elem.getElementsByTagName("...")`.

Note that option 3 only returns elements, but searches all descendants, while options 1 and 2 returns all node type, but only direct children.

Answer (score 0):

Access the attributes as following:

```
            Element traceElem = doc.getDocumentElement();
            Element elem = (Element) traceElem.getElementsByTagName( "string" ).item( 0 );
            System.out.println( elem.getAttribute( "key" ));
            System.out.println( elem.getAttribute( "value" ));
```